# rewrite goroutine function and do recover

Tags: go

I want to write a function for recover goroutine painc, the below demo has recover goroutine painc for "test1", but not support for "test2", "test3", "test4".
How can I just write a function for recover any goroutine painc.

```golang
func main() {
    go myGoroutine(test1)
    time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
}

func myGoroutine(realGoFunc func()) {
    defer func() {
        if err := recover(); err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
    }

    realGoFunc()
}

func test1() {
    fmt.Println("test1 come here)
    painc("test1 error")
    fmt.Println("test1 end")
}

func test2(username string) {
    fmt.Println("test2 come here)
    painc("test2 error")
    fmt.Println("test2 end")
}

func test3(userId int64, username string) {
    fmt.Println("test3 come here)
    painc("test3 error")
    fmt.Println("test3 end")
}

func test4(user *User) {
    fmt.Println("test4 come here)
    painc("test4 error")
    fmt.Println("test4 end")
}
```

Comment: You cannot do this like you try to do. Go is statically typed. You cannot write a function which takes an arbitrary function. This is unrelated to catching panics. Catch the panic in main.

Comment: Use a closure: https://play.golang.org/p/ZFD_LOMzALs

Answer (score 0):

In your case, a possible (but not nice) choise is using context:

```golang
type User struct {
    name string
    uid  int64
}


func main() {

    user := &User{
        name: "hezhixiong",
        uid:  int64(58741634),
    }

    ctx := context.WithValue(context.Background(), "name", user.name)
    ctx = context.WithValue(ctx, "uid", user.uid)
    ctx = context.WithValue(ctx, "user", user)

    go SafeFunc(test1, ctx)
    go SafeFunc(test2, ctx)
    go SafeFunc(test3, ctx)
    go SafeFunc(test4, ctx)

    for {
    }
}

func test1(ctx context.Context) {
    panic("test1")
}

func test2(ctx context.Context) {
    name := ctx.Value("name").(string)
    panic(name)
}

func test3(ctx context.Context) {
    name := ctx.Value("name").(string)
    uid := ctx.Value("uid").(int64)
    panic(fmt.Sprintln(name, uid))
}

func test4(ctx context.Context) {
    user := ctx.Value("user").(*User)
    panic(user)
}

// SafeFunc safe function call
func SafeFunc(f func(context.Context), ctx context.Context) {
    defer func() {
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            fmt.Println(r)
        }
    }()
    f(ctx)
}
```

In our production, we usually warp the input and ouput like this:

```golang
func test(in *input) (out *output) {
    // parse in
    // ... do something
    // build out
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fix it by anonymous function.

```
func main() {
    // add go func() {}
    go func() {
      myGoroutine(test1)
    }
    // add go func() {}
    go func() {
      myGoroutine(test1)
    }
    time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
}

func myGoroutine(realGoFunc func()) {
    defer func() {
        if err := recover(); err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
    }

    realGoFunc()
}
```